# start a process in a cmd window and get output

Tags: java, process, cmd

I want to start a process in a CMD window with Java, and the easiest way to do that is by

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start program.exe")
```

The problem is that now I can't get the input from the process. How can I get the output from the process and be able to run it in a separate CMD window?

Comment: I don't think you can.  From what I understand, `start` will start a new process...the output of which is not sent back to the command...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `start` is a separate command whose purpose is to launch a completely new process unrelated to the `cmd` that invokes `start`.  Whatever `start` then executes is not connected to the original `cmd` and cannot be accessed by your Java program.

If you need to access the subprocess' in/out/err streams, do not use `start`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey bro if you want to println the output process of your process use this

```
Process process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start program.exe");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

with this you will get each output process exactly the same with cmd output.

if you want to process 2 cmd maybe you can make 2 process with different exec

```
Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start program1.exe");
Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start program2.exe");
```

if you want this run with same thread please read java books about thread, you can run it at the same time with thread.